# aria-label contain HTML text but want to listen only text without html elements description

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accessibility

I'm working on accessibility of a div, just want to show tooltip-html value in aria-label, but tooltip-HTML value contains HTML element like a paragraph when I use that screen reader also start reading HTML  element as well character by character, so I need a solution for that screen reader shouldn't read HTML characters.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in responseData" class="d-sla__icon d-icon-right-{{item.icon}}" ng-style="{'left':item.percent}" tooltip-placement="{{item.tooltipPlacement}}"
            uib-tooltip-html="'{{item.tooltip}}'" ng-click="showMilestones(item)" 
            tooltip-trigger="focus mouseenter" aria-label="'{{item.tooltip}}'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although implementation may differ from one screen reader to another, by default, the `aria-label` value should only contain text and not HTML markup.

You can change your setup to use the `aria-labelledby` attribute instead and point to another element by reference which would have greater support for HTML markup.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in responseData" class="d-sla__icon d-icon-right-{{item.icon}}" ng-style="{'left':item.percent}" tooltip-placement="{{item.tooltipPlacement}}"
            uib-tooltip-html="'{{item.tooltip}}'" ng-click="showMilestones(item)" 
            tooltip-trigger="focus mouseenter" aria-labelledby="itemTooltip"></div>

<h4 id="itemTooltip">'{{item.tooltip}}'</h4>
```

Also, you may consider using `aria-describedby` if the tooltip content is more of a description than a title/label of the given element.